# MongoDB change DBrefs

Tags: json, mongodb, database

is there a way to change a MongoDB collection reference?
With change I mean the value in the reference. 
I can't just create a direct link because the database is in use.
My structure looks like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4e7c6b47e4b0dea06288ad21"),
        "license" : "ABC123",
        "model" : "911",
        "make" : "Porsche",
        "owner" : {
                "$ref" : "users",
                "$id" : "Test User"
        }
}
```

I want to change the ID like

```
{ "$ref" : "users", "$id" : "NEW USER"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, but you can't do it with a direct $set :

```
> db.test.save({a:{$ref:"users", $id:"Test User"}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1e85489d086ee4511551b6"), "a" : DBRef("users", "Test User") }
> db.test.update({}, {$set:{'a.$id':"NEW USER"}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1e85489d086ee4511551b6"), "a" : { "$id" : "NEW USER", "$ref" : "users" } }
```

As you can see this breaks the references because the DBRef specification demands the order of the $ref and $id fields to be $ref first.

You can update it like this :

```
> db.test.update({}, {$set:{a:{$ref:"users", $id:"NEW USER"}}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1e858b9d086ee4511551b7"), "a" : DBRef("users", "NEW USER") }
```

Or just use "new DBRef(..)" if you're in shell.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have started to avoid DBRef entirely since it adds a lot of unnecessary overhead since in my case all objects referred to by the "user" field are in the same collection, making the first part of DBRef redudant.

So I would migrate to a new field (let's say "ownerId") and just store the ObjectId directly in there. Obviously you will may need to do some manual retrieval of the user object, but this will depending on your application framework.